# How to sigInt rabbit MQ workers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq

We are using Rabbit MQ as a message broker via Sneaker gem.

During the deployment time, we need to pause the connection. So no worker's work is picked up by the worker after completion of the current work

Is there any way to use CLI or Rabbit MQ management screen to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rabbit MQ(Sneakers) provides SIGTERM as gracefully termination of pods.

Kill -Sigterm pid_number
Will make sure all existing work are done and then terminate the pod